# How to get modules of 3d tensors in 4d torch tensor?

Tags: python-3.x, pytorch

I have a torch tensor with 4 dimensions.
It's shape is [50, 1, 1, 200]. I have to get a list with modules of 200 hundred 3d tensors. Which is the easiest way to do so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try `torch.unbind` (https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.unbind.html)?

```
a = torch.rand(50, 1, 1, 200)
b = torch.unbind(dim=3)

len(b)      # 200
b[0].shape  # torch.Size([50, 1, 1])
```